# Group data in DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datatable

I got a datatable which I get from an Excel file. Now, I want to sum the Quantity1 and Quantity2 column of the datatable which grouping by Block, Transplant and Variety. Is it possible to do so?

This is the datatable I get from an Excel file:

[image]

and this is the result I need:

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using - Excel? (The answer may be product specific.)

Comment: SQL, I want to get the data from excel to insert into database

Comment: SQL is a language, not a database. Perhaps you mean MS SQL Server?

Comment: `DataTable` is DB independent, being a disconnected Architecture component

Comment: yea, it's MS SQL Server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should get you started. Note that the following code was written in Linqpad, so `.Dump()` will only work there. You should probably replace the Transplant type with `DateTime` in production. I left it as string for simplicity.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
dt.Clear();
dt.Columns.Add("Block");
dt.Columns.Add("Transplant");
dt.Columns.Add("Variety");
dt.Columns.Add("Quantity1");
dt.Columns.Add("Quantity2");


object[] r1 = {"A", "04/04/2017", "ROSE", 11, 11};
object[] r2 = {"A", "04/04/2017", "ROSE", 21, 11};
object[] r3 = {"B", "14/04/2017", "MN", 231, 11};
object[] r4 = {"A", "24/04/2017", "GG", 11, 11};
object[] r5 = {"A", "24/04/2017", "GG", 21, 21};

dt.Rows.Add(r1);
dt.Rows.Add(r2);
dt.Rows.Add(r3);
dt.Rows.Add(r4);
dt.Rows.Add(r5);
dt.Dump();

var grouped = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy (d => new 
              { 
                    block = d.Field<string>("Block"), 
                    transplant = d.Field<string>("Transplant"), 
                    variety = d.Field<string>("Variety") 
              })
              .Select(x => new {
                    Block = x.Key.block,
                    Transplant = x.Key.transplant,
                    Variety = x.Key.variety,
                    //replace ItemArray Index with appropriate values in your code
                    Q1 = x.Sum(y => int.Parse(y.ItemArray[3].ToString())),
                    Q2 = x.Sum(y => int.Parse(y.ItemArray[4].ToString())),
                });
grouped.Dump();
```

Output:

[image]

The first table is the raw source data, and the second table shows you what would come out of it.

Answer (score 2):

**Edited the answer, as my understanding regarding the requirements were incorrect, we need to GroupBy using the columns** - `Block (string),Transplant(Datetime),Variety(string)` and create the sum of `Quantity1 (int),Quantity2 (int)`

Following code shall help (It use the Linq API):

```
var groupingResult =
dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => new {Block = (string)row["Block"] , Transplant = (DateTime)row["Transplant"], Variety = (string)row["Variety"]},row => new {Sum = (int)row["Quantity1"] + (int)row["Quantity2"]});
```

This will provide a result data structure like:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<<Anonymous type: string Block,DateTime Transplant,string Variety>,<Anonymous type: int Sum>>>
```

Now you can  convert it into a IEnumerable as follows:

```
var resultData = groupingResult.Select(grp => new {grp.Key.Block,grp.Key.Transplant,grp.Key.Variety,Sum = grp.Sum(r => r.Sum)});
```

Which is of type `IEnumerable<<Anonymous type: string Block,DateTime Transplant,string Variety,int Sum>>`

It consists of the Columns `Block (string), Transplant (DateTime), Variety (string), Sum (int)`